# single query to fetch rows from mysql table using count(*) of two coloumns

Tags: mysql

I have a table named Table2 whose definition is as below.

```
Id  int False   
Source  nvarchar(MAX)   True    
Dest    nvarchar(MAX)   True    
Port    nvarchar(MAX)   True    
DgmLen  nvarchar(MAX)   True    
Flags   nvarchar(MAX)   True    
Payload nvarchar(MAX)   True
```

Now I want to print all the rows of this table whose "source & DgmLen" count is greater than 6.

Firstly I have used this query to fetch the count of sources in the table:

```
Select DgmLen,Port from Table2 group by Port,DgmLen having count(*) > 6
```

and it has has fetched the following data:

```
DgmLen      Port
7-48    5-139
```

Now I want to print all the rows having "DgmLen = 7-48" and "Port=5-139" from Table2.

How can write this in a **single query** to fetch rows having **unique set of value in DgmLen and Port fields/coloumns**.

Comment: sorry that was a type mistake, am updating it

Comment: @eggyal this is not the same question, here I want to fetch the rows having unique two fields/columns

Answer (score 0):

Simply join your resultset back to your table:

```
SELECT * FROM Table2 NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT DgmLen, Port FROM Table2 GROUP BY Port, DgmLen HAVING COUNT(*) > 6
) t
```

Comment: @user3638178: Are you sure you're using MySQL?

Comment: @kcmaharshi: I've never heard of "C# Database server", but if you're using a database server that's called something other than "MySQL" then you're not using MySQL.